# OpenGL render to texture causing edge artifacts

Tags: opengl

This is my first post here so any help would be massively appreciated :)

I'm using C++ with SDL and OpenGL 3.3

When rendering directly to screen I get the following result

[image: Render To Screen]

And when I render to texture I this happens

[image: Render To Texture]

Anti-aliasing is turned off for both. I'm guessing this has something to do with depth buffer accuracy but I've tried a lot of different methods to improve the result but, no success :( I'm currently using the following code to set up my FBO:

```
GLuint frameBufferID;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBufferID);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferID);

glGenTextures(1, &coloursTextureID);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, coloursTextureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);



//Depth buffer setup

GLuint depthrenderbuffer;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthrenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);


glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, coloursTextureID, 0);

GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers); // 

if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        return false;
```

Thank you so much for any help :)

Comment: I fixed it!!!!! Finally!!!!!

Turns out all that was required was a tiny change in the line:

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0);

to

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB32F,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0);

[This tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial35/tutorial35.html) saved the day!

Any help understanding why changing GL_RGB to GL_RGB32F solved the problem would still be greatly appreciated!

Thanks to Heckel for helping reformat my question :)

Comment: That's very odd that changing the color buffer format would have that result. After all the screen is not a 32F buffer, but you could render to the screen without those artifacts. Using a 32F buffer will also hurt performance if you are rendering a lot to it (though it might not matter for you now).

Comment: Be sure to submit your own answer on the question & accept it so others can find it :)

Comment: @Nathan yeah it is strange as it looked like a problem with the depth buffer, sad to hear it will reduce performance but it seems to be fine at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!!!!! Finally!!!!!

Turns out all that was required was a tiny change in the line:

```
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIG‌NED_BYTE,0);
```

to

```
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB32F,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,GL_RGB,GL_UN‌​SIGNED_BYTE,0);
```

[This tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial35/tutorial35.html) saved the day! Any help understanding why changing GL_RGB to GL_RGB32F solved the problem would still be greatly appreciated! Thanks to Heckel for helping reformat my question :)